# Linkedin api call using oauth in java

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am trying to fetch Linkedin company updates to my website. Followed the process https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication and generated api key and secret key by registering.

According to the [documentation](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication) I am able to generate the Authorization Code in Step a.
For Step b to generate Access Token I am using [OAuth in java](http://oauth.net/2/).

```
request = OAuthClientRequest.tokenLocation("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken")
                        .setGrantType(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                        .setCode("****")
                        .setRedirectURI("https://www.example.in")
                        .setClientId("*******")
                        .setClientSecret("******").buildBodyMessage();
                    OAuthClient oAuthClient = new OAuthClient(new URLConnectionClient());
                    GitHubTokenResponse oAuthResponse = oAuthClient.accessToken(request, GitHubTokenResponse.class);
                    String accessToken = oAuthResponse.getAccessToken();
                    String expiresIn = oAuthResponse.getExpiresIn();
```

But getting error

```
OAuthProblemException{description='Missing parameters: access_token', error='invalid_request', uri='null', state='null', scope='null'}
at org.apache.amber.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthProblemException.error(OAuthProblemException.java:57)
at org.apache.amber.oauth2.common.utils.OAuthUtils.handleOAuthProblemException(OAuthUtils.java:166)
at org.apache.amber.oauth2.common.utils.OAuthUtils.handleMissingParameters(OAuthUtils.java:184)
at org.apache.amber.oauth2.client.validator.OAuthClientValidator.validateRequiredParameters(OAuthClientValidator.java:90)
at org.apache.amber.oauth2.client.validator.OAuthClientValidator.validateParameters(OAuthClientValidator.java:53)
at org.apache.amber.oauth2.client.validator.OAuthClientValidator.validate(OAuthClientValidator.java:49)
at org.apache.amber.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.validate(OAuthClientResponse.java:64)
at org.apache.amber.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.init(OAuthClientResponse.java:59)
at org.apache.amber.oauth2.client.response.OAuthAccessTokenResponse.init(OAuthAccessTokenResponse.java:52)
at org.apache.amber.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponseFactory.createCustomResponse(OAuthClientResponseFactory.java:60)
at org.apache.amber.oauth2.client.URLConnectionClient.execute(URLConnectionClient.java:105)
```

Please help to fix this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spotted the issue.

Looks like there is a problem in the documentation.
Apologies.

Right call is

```
request = OAuthClientRequest.tokenLocation("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken")
                    .setGrantType(ResponseType.CODE.toString())
                    .setCode("****")
                    .setRedirectURI("https://www.example.in")
                    .setClientId("*******")
                    .setClientSecret("******").buildBodyMessage();
```

Mind `ResponseType.CODE.toString()` rather than `GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE`

Comment: Thanks Antonio, Just tried this one and getting compilation error The method setGrantType(GrantType) in the type OAuthClientRequest.TokenRequestBuilder is not 
 applicable for the arguments (String). Do I need to make any tweek.

Comment: oopps apologies. I have mixed the authentication location with the token one. The issue is that you might want to use the OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.class rather then the GitHubTokenResponse.class for Linkedin: OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse oAuthResponse = oAuthClient.accessToken(request, OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.class); We are in the process on improving our API and the documentation. I do realize this is a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks Antonio, Finally I am able to call.

Comment: @Bhabani,  Antonio - May I request you what scope details we need to set ? and what would be the OAuthBearerClientRequest request url ? Please reply

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go through some of the linkedin developer docs [here](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication), and check out a java [OAuth library](http://oauth.net/code/) rather than performing the signing process by hand. Then you can ask a specific question.